# Wordpress menu hover and active page elements

Tags: wordpress, menu, highlight

I'm trying to build a menu like here
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/46852.html

Still learning, and of course i went with something that was most logical to me.
At first i was gonna do a:hover solid border, but couldn't figure out setting up height of li, to put highlight way on top, and putting that arrow in the middle (putting that arrow there at all, for that matter).

Then, i thought of hover background image, but it didn't appear at all, and once again, I couldn't think of way to put the arrow in the middle.

Can somebody, please, point me in right direction?

Tnx

Comment: Excuse me if I understand you wrong but this might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/ZRtHF/ You just have to style it for your own

Comment: that helps with the triangle part. tnx! What about putting it way on top of the menu?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ytgs8/131/ look at this, there is a triangle on top - you have to style it like you want